# removing seconds from date-time column in R

Tags: r, strptime

I have a column in this format :

2015-02-20 20:11:20.639794
2015-11-12 20:12:33.055875
2016-04-02 04:43:02

I used *strptime* in R to create a format to my liking but the problem is that seconds value is still there as zeros (see below). Is there an easy way to remove seconds value from the date-time column? I would prefer not to use another library for this.

2015-02-20 20:11:00
2015-11-12 20:12:00
2016-04-02 04:43:00

```
data$measured_at <- strptime(data$measured_at,  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: Use `strftime` instead.

Comment: That just makes time all zeros like so: 2015-02-20 00:00. I would like to preserve the hour and minutes like so  - 2015-02-20 20:11.

Comment: After whatever you have done, now format it again: `format(data$measured_at ,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`

Answer (score 1):

## use `base::substr()`

Another way to accomplish this, although you'd have to convert the resulting character vector back into a date if you needed it in that format, is to use `base::substr()`.

```
> temp <- "2015-02-20 20:11:00"
> substr(temp, 1, 16)
[1] "2015-02-20 20:11"
```